# O que eu poderia fazer para esse except não interromper o meu else?

Tags: python, python-3.x

Esta é minha linha de códigos, eu gostaria que este except não interferisse no meu ultimo else, mas de todas as maneira que eu tentei, deram errado.

```
#frameworks usados
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame



#DATABASE (Onde ficam as informações base da tabela.)
database = DataFrame
database = {'Jogos':[1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'Placar':[12, 24, 10, 24],
    'Mínimo da Temporada':[12, 12, 10, 10],
    'Máximo da Temporada':[12, 24, 24, 24],
    'Quebra recorde mín':[0, 0, 1, 1],
    'Quebra recorde max':[0, 1, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(database, columns = ['Jogos', 'Placar', 'Mínimo da Temporada', 'Máximo da Temporada', 'Quebra recorde mín', 'Quebra recorde max'])
Data_Table = df.to_string()


'''
O input, para o usuario poder adicionar novas informações a tabela.
Caso seja inserido uma string ou um int abaixo de 0, ele irá requisitar uma nova tentativa
'''
while True:
    try:
        p = int(input("Qual foi o placar?:"))
        if p == p > 0:
           break
        else: raise ValueError('tente novamente:')
    except ValueError as e:
            print('Valor inválido,', e)
            
                
        


j = df['Jogos'].iloc[-1] + 1

'''
Cálcula o mínimo e máximo da temporada.
Define o valor base de mint e maxt como sendo o ultimo 
valor das suas respectivas colunas e verifica, no caso de mint,
se o valor mínimo anterior era maior que o placar atual
Faz a mesma coisa com maxt, apenas invertendo
'''

mint = df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
if int(p) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
    mint = p

maxt = df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
if int(p) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
    maxt = p


'''    
Cálcula as quebras de recordes.
Define o valor base de qrmin e qrmax como sendo o ultimo 
valor das suas respectivas colunas e verifica se houve mudança nas
colunas de mínimo e máximo da temporada, para modificar o valor da quebra de recordes.

'''
qrmin = df['Quebra recorde mín'].iloc[-1]
if int(mint) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-2]:
    qrmin = qrmin + 1

qrmax = df['Quebra recorde max'].iloc[-1]
if int(maxt) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-2]:
    qrmax = qrmax + 1
"""
Adiciona novas linhas com as informações dos cálculos e afins, a tabela.

Define qual variável muda o resultado de cada coluna, depois
assimila a nova linha ao dataframe com o código df.append
"""
new_row = {'Jogos':j, 'Placar': p, 'Mínimo da Temporada': mint, 'Máximo da Temporada': maxt, 'Quebra recorde mín':qrmin, 'Quebra recorde max': qrmax,}
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

#Coloca em prática os códigos e lê o dataframe.
print(df)

'''
Ocorrem todos os comandos para criar novas linhas e assimila-las ao dataframe novamente, 
além dos cálculos.

O processo funciona igual ao do while anterior, com a diferença que ele já vem integrado
com o "new_row", "df.append" "print(df)"
'''

while True:
    continuar = input('Deseja continuar? Sim ou não:').lower()
    try: 
        if continuar == 'sim' or 's':
            p = int(input("Adicione algum placar:"))
        
            if p > 0:
        
                j = (df)['Jogos'].iloc[-1] + 1

                mint = df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
                if int(p) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    mint = p

                maxt = df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
                if int(p) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    maxt = p
        
                qrmin = df['Quebra recorde mín'].iloc[-1]
                if int(mint) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    qrmin = (qrmin + 1)

                qrmax = df['Quebra recorde max'].iloc[-1]
                if int(maxt) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    qrmax = (qrmax + 1)

                new_row = {'Jogos':j, 'Placar': p, 'Mínimo da Temporada': mint, 'Máximo da Temporada': maxt, 'Quebra recorde mín':qrmin, 'Quebra recorde max': qrmax,}
                df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True) 

                print(df)
            else:
                raise ValueError('Valor inválido, tente novamente:', )
        else:
            break
            
    except ValueError as e:
            print( e)
```

Obs: Estou iniciando na programação em python então provável que tenham erros de syntax.

Comment: Gabriel, bom dia! Ele interfere como? Qual o comportamento que você espera? Abraço!

Comment: O que o programa deveria fazer exatamente? Poderia [edit] a pergunta e colocar mais informações? De qualquer forma, `if p == p > 0` não faz sentido, o resultado de `p > 0` é um booleano, então vc está comparando um `booleano` com um número, que provavelmente não é o que vc quer - não seria só `if p > 0`? E lançar um `ValueError` só para forçar que caia no `except` não me parece uma boa (porque não imprimir a mensagem no `else` e pronto?)

Comment: Minha intenção era que se `if continuar = "sim"`, ele rodasse aquele código dentro desse mesmo `if`, e caso fosse qualquer coisa além dessa resposta, ele fechasse o programa. Agradeço bastante pela ajuda, eu sei que é fora do tópico e do tema desse fórum, mas poderiam me recomendar livros ou afins para eu aperfeiçoar meu conhecimento em programação, entrei nessa área e tem tanta coisa pra aprender que nem sei por onde começar.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Mantendo (quase) todo o seu código, você pode passar o `continuar = input('Deseja continuar? Sim ou não:').lower()` para dentro do while, dessa forma a cada iteração ele irá perguntar se você deseja continuar e não irá entrar em loop infinito.

```
#frameworks usados
import pandas as pd
from pandas import DataFrame

#DATABASE (Onde ficam as informações base da tabela.)
database = DataFrame
database = {'Jogos':[1, 2, 3, 4], 
    'Placar':[12, 24, 10, 24],
    'Mínimo da Temporada':[12, 12, 10, 10],
    'Máximo da Temporada':[12, 24, 24, 24],
    'Quebra recorde mín':[0, 0, 1, 1],
    'Quebra recorde max':[0, 1, 1, 1]}

df = pd.DataFrame(database, columns = ['Jogos', 'Placar', 'Mínimo da Temporada', 'Máximo da Temporada', 'Quebra recorde mín', 'Quebra recorde max'])
Data_Table = df.to_string()

'''
O input, para o usuario poder adicionar novas informações a tabela.
Caso seja inserido uma string ou um int abaixo de 0, ele irá requisitar uma nova tentativa
'''
while True:
    try:
        p = int(input("Qual foi o placar?:"))
        if p == p > 0:
            break
        else: raise ValueError('tente novamente:')
    except ValueError as e:
            print('Valor inválido,', e)
            
                
j = df['Jogos'].iloc[-1] + 1

'''
Cálcula o mínimo e máximo da temporada.
Define o valor base de mint e maxt como sendo o ultimo 
valor das suas respectivas colunas e verifica, no caso de mint,
se o valor mínimo anterior era maior que o placar atual
Faz a mesma coisa com maxt, apenas invertendo
'''

mint = df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
if int(p) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
    mint = p

maxt = df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
if int(p) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
    maxt = p

'''    
Cálcula as quebras de recordes.
Define o valor base de qrmin e qrmax como sendo o ultimo 
valor das suas respectivas colunas e verifica se houve mudança nas
colunas de mínimo e máximo da temporada, para modificar o valor da quebra de recordes.

'''
qrmin = df['Quebra recorde mín'].iloc[-1]
if int(mint) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-2]:
    qrmin = qrmin + 1

qrmax = df['Quebra recorde max'].iloc[-1]
if int(maxt) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-2]:
    qrmax = qrmax + 1
"""
Adiciona novas linhas com as informações dos cálculos e afins, a tabela.

Define qual variável muda o resultado de cada coluna, depois
assimila a nova linha ao dataframe com o código df.append
"""
new_row = {'Jogos':j, 'Placar': p, 'Mínimo da Temporada': mint, 'Máximo da Temporada': maxt, 'Quebra recorde mín':qrmin, 'Quebra recorde max': qrmax,}
df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True)

#Coloca em prática os códigos e lê o dataframe.
print(df)

'''
Ocorrem todos os comandos para criar novas linhas e assimila-las ao dataframe novamente, 
além dos cálculos.

O processo funciona igual ao do while anterior, com a diferença que ele já vem integrado
com o "new_row", "df.append" "print(df)"
'''

while True:
    continuar = input('Deseja continuar? Sim ou não:').lower()
    try: 
        if continuar == 'sim' or continuar == 's':
            p = int(input("Adicione algum placar:"))
        
            if p > 0:
        
                j = (df)['Jogos'].iloc[-1] + 1

                mint = df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
                if int(p) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    mint = p

                maxt = df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]
                if int(p) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    maxt = p
        
                qrmin = df['Quebra recorde mín'].iloc[-1]
                if int(mint) < df['Mínimo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    qrmin = (qrmin + 1)

                qrmax = df['Quebra recorde max'].iloc[-1]
                if int(maxt) > df['Máximo da Temporada'].iloc[-1]:
                    qrmax = (qrmax + 1)

                new_row = {'Jogos':j, 'Placar': p, 'Mínimo da Temporada': mint, 'Máximo da Temporada': maxt, 'Quebra recorde mín':qrmin, 'Quebra recorde max': qrmax,}
                df = df.append(new_row, ignore_index=True) 

                print(df)
        else:
            #raise ValueError('Valor inválido, tente novamente:', )
            break
                       
    except ValueError as e:
            print( e)
```

Adicionei o `lower()` só para sempre comparar com uma string minúscula. Removi o `break` que estava dentro do ultimo else, pois não é necessário.

Dentro do `else`, acima do except eu coloquei o `break` ali.

---

Edit

No código atual o erro estava em `if continuar == 'sim' or 's'`, onde na verdade deveria ser `if continuar == 'sim' or continuar == 's'`

Comment: Utilizando esse código, ele já ficou bem mais próximo do que eu gostaria que fosse, obrigado. Como eu faria para quando fosse qualquer coisa além do `"sim"` fechasse o programa? Pois esse `else: break` era pra fechar por completo todo o loop juntamente com o programa. Agradeço desde já.

Comment: Gabriel, ótimo! Por nada! Abraços!

Comment: Como eu faria para quando fosse qualquer coisa além do "sim" fechasse o programa? Eu tentei usar o `else: break` para isso, mas ele segue perguntando se desejo continuar, num loop interminável.

Comment: Veja que antes do except eu coloquei um `break` dentro de um else, creio que isso resolva seu problema.

Comment: Eu utilizei ele também, mas continua dando o problema infelizmente.

Comment: Ai eu teria que ver como está todo o seu código, pois da forma que coloquei aqui o programa para. Você está utilizando o jupyter notebook?

Comment: Veja: [gif](http://g.recordit.co/RqP0hJoYTB.gif)

Comment: Vamos [continuar esta discussão no chat](https://chat.stackexchange.com/rooms/113665/discussion-between-gabriel-junges-and-lmonferrari).